# How to have automatic line breaks in cvitem within cventry in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I would be really grateful, if anybody could help with this. If I compile the code (see MWE below) the text that is written in the second argument of cvitem continues beyond the right margin until the very end of the paper. What do I need to do in order to have automatic line breaks in the second argument of `\cvitem`?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=cyan,urlcolor=cyan}}


\firstname{Jane}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Street}{City}{}
\mobile{Number}
\email{email}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry
{2020--2025}
{Degree}
{University}
{Location}
{Some info including a link in my real document. The automatic linebreak works here, but not below}
{\cvitem{Item 1}{This is the description of item 1 and it is very long so I need an automatic linebreak here so the text doesn't go beyond the linewidth.}
\cvitem{Item 2}{This is the description of item 2 and it is very long so I need an automatic linebreak here which I don't know how to create.}
\cvitem{Item 3}{This is the description of item 3 and it is even longer and spans across multiple lines so I need an automatic linebreak so the text doesn't go beyond the linewidth, but I don't know how to create this.}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line break *does* happen automatically. The problem is that you are missing an argument to `\cventry`, then it takes the `\cvitem`s as argument.

From [`moderncv`'s GitHub page](https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/blob/master/examples/template.tex), the arguments to `\cventry` are:

```
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description} % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
```

and you didn't have `\textit{Grade}`. You must have this argument, even if empty (`{}`).

```
I also removed the braces that were grouping the `\cvitem`s.
```

If you want to change the alignment of the `\cvitem`s you should, instead, increase the value of `\hintscolumnwidth` and decrease that of `\maincolumnwidth`. The `\cvitem`s are typeset using a `tabular` with two columns each with one of those two widths.

For example, to make indentation of `Item X` be `4cm`:

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm}% The width of the "hints" column
\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}% Recompute the size of the remaining text.
```

[image]

Compilable MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=cyan,urlcolor=cyan}}

\firstname{Jane}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Street}{City}{}
\mobile{Number}
\email{email}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}

\cventry
{2020--2025}
{Degree}
{University}
{Location}
{\textit{Grade}}% Missing this
{Some info including a link in my real document. The automatic linebreak works here, but not below}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm}
\setlength{\maincolumnwidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\hintscolumnwidth-\separatorcolumnwidth}

\cvitem{Item 1}{This is the description of item 1 and it is very long so I need an automatic linebreak here so the text doesn't go beyond the linewidth.}
\cvitem{Item 2}{This is the description of item 2 and it is very long so I need an automatic linebreak here which I don't know how to create.}
\cvitem{Item 3}{This is the description of item 3 and it is even longer and spans across multiple lines so I need an automatic linebreak so the text doesn't go beyond the linewidth, but I don't know how to create this.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Actually, I was trying to put the three '\cvitem's within the last argument of \cventry, so that the enumeration is indented. But then the line break doesn't work like it should. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Mica You're welcome :) You shouldn't put the `\cvitem`s as arguments to `\cventry`. The typesetting rules are different and the result you'll get will be further from what you want. You can, on the other hand, change the layout of the `\cvitem`s. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: @Mica If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately, I don't have enough points to upvote.

Comment: @Mica It's all right :). I thought users could upvote answers from their own questions... Glad it helped.